# Bamboo maven build suddenly started failing: No compiler is provided in this environment

Tags: maven, bamboo

We have a Bamboo build that includes a multi-module Maven build task, for a mixed scala/java project.

*The build has worked fine for many months*, but started failing today.

Maven successfully builds several modules, then consistently fails on a particular module, with the error:

```
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment.
        Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
```

However, a JDK is installed, and this module compiles and builds fine if I log into the bamboo server and run maven manually just for this module.

`JAVA_HOME` appears to be set correctly on the bamboo server and points to a valid JDK, and I can run `javac -version` without issue.

No updates have been made to this server recently.

How can we fix this build?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem (though not the root cause).

The Maven module that fails is the first one that includes java source files (rather than pure scala), so it is the first module for which Maven tries to invoke `javac`.

The Maven task in Bamboo specifies a particular named JDK profile.

Checking the Bamboo settings for this JDK, I found that it is set to a path that actually points to a JRE (as indicated by the original error message).

(A JRE is no good because it doesn't include the `javac` compiler and other build tools).

It is not clear how this path got changed/corrupted (nobody else had access to the server, so it suggests an issue within Bamboo itself) but editing this path to point to the installed JDK again fixes the build.